# I need xml tag that work like not ifconfig (!ifconfig)

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, xml, system.xml, confirmation

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="support">
            <label>Support</label>
            <url ifconfig="support_options/support_data/support_pop" ><![CDATA[javascript:div_show();]]></url>
            <title>Support</title>
            <prepare/><urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            </action>
            <action method="addLink" ifconfig="support_options/support_setting/support_set" translate="label title" module="support">
            <label>Support</label>
            <url>support</url>
            <title>Support</title>
            <prepare/><urlParams/>
            <position>100</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

I want to pass 2 url at one link and put validation on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such thing.

But the check for ifconfig is in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` -> `function _generateAction`:

```
if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

so eventually you can add something like this below the previous code:

```
if (isset($node['ifnotconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifnotconfig'])) {
    if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and to check with:

```
<action ifnotconfig="..."
```